# If a Lithium-Ion/Poly pouch cell is included in a product, what certifications does the battery itself require?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, certification

Imagine you were creating a new product, perhaps a bluetooth speaker or smart home device, where a rechargable lithium-ion cell was contained within the device. You intend to certify th

When sourcing the battery, what certifications would you need to ensure to be confident it would not impact the certification of the product?

The intent would be to sell the product in Europe and North America.

Comment: That would be defined by where you intend to sell the device. Different countries have different requirements so be sure to give that info so someone can make a better answer. The company making the batteries might be able to help you if you tell them where you intend to sell the devices.